# How to do Pagination with MS-ACCESS and JSP?

Tags: jsp, ms-access

I am using MS-Access DB with JSP and I want to do pagination in my code for searching data in the DB. 
I am using following query but its not working:

```
String q="Select TOP 5 * " +
    "From ( " +
    "Select TOP ("+totalRows+" - (("+iPageNo+" - 1) * 5))  " +
        "From Registration " +
        "Order By LName DESC) " +
    "where FName like'" + fname + "%' " +
        "AND LName like '" + lname + "%' " +
        "AND MName like '" +mname + "%' " ;
ps1=conn.prepareStatement(q);
rs1=ps1.executeQuery();
```

It isn't displaying anything.
Please tell me where am I mistaking.

Comment: Does the query you are storing in the Q string return what you expect when you query the DB from an SQL client?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the right wildcard character for the version/configuration of MS Access that you are using?

The default (for the old versions at least, and possibly the current version) is `*`, not `%`.

Comment: The wildcard for DAO is *, for ADO, MS Access in SQL92 mode and using  Alike is %. In this case, it is %, I suspect. I do not believe it has ever been related to versions.

Comment: And if the DB is still in SQL89/86 mode (which I suspect it is), what functionality should the OP expect?

Comment: JDBC is similar to ODBC and setting the SQL mode in Access is only relevant to quesries carried out in Access, not the Jet/ACE engine, AFAIK, in addition, this item http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795843/jdbc-and-ms-access-problem shows % as the wildcard.